# Socket message hangs until thread completes in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets

I am trying to write Perl code that does two-way communication over a Unix socket.  It needs to do the following things:

1. Client code sends a request over the socket
2. Server code reads the request
3. Server performs any actions that should happen immediately
4. Server creates a new thread to do additional actions that may take a long time
5. Server sends response over the socket
6. Client receives response
7. The new thread continues to work after the response has been sent

I have gotten most of this to work now, but with one problem.  Steps 1 - 5 work fine, but at step 6, the client is unable to read the response until AFTER the thread has exited. (even though the response was sent more-or-less immediately)  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Perl 5.10.1 on Ubuntu Lucid.

Here's an example:

**Client code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Socket;

my $socket_name = 'catsock';
my $client_message = "Hello server, this is the client.";

my $SOCK;
socket($SOCK, PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die "socket: $!";
connect($SOCK, sockaddr_un($socket_name)) or die "connect: $!";

$| = 1, select $_ for select $SOCK; # turn on autoflush
print $SOCK $client_message; # send the message
shutdown($SOCK,1); # finished writing
print "sent:     $client_message\n";

my $server_message = do { local $/; <$SOCK> }; # get the response
print "recieved: $server_message\n\n";
```

**Server code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Socket;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub threadfunc
{
    print "    waiting 5 seconds in new thread...\n";
    sleep(5);
    print "    exiting thread...\n\n";
}

my $server_message = "Hello client, this is the server.";
my $socket_name = 'catsock';

my $SERVER;
my $CLIENT;
socket($SERVER, PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die "socket: $!";
unlink($socket_name);
bind($SERVER, sockaddr_un($socket_name)) or die "bind: $!";
chmod(0660, $socket_name);
listen($SERVER, SOMAXCONN) or die "listen: $!";

print "server started on $socket_name\n\n";

while(1) {
    accept($CLIENT, $SERVER);

    my $client_message = do { local $/; <$CLIENT> }; # grab entire message
    print "recieved: $client_message\n";

    print "creating new thread...\n";
    my $thr = threads->create(\&threadfunc);
    $thr->detach();

    print $CLIENT $server_message; # send the response
    print "sent: $server_message\n\n";

    close $CLIENT;
}
```

When I run this, the following things happen:

1. Client sends "Hello server, this is the client."
2. Server receives client's message
3. Server creates a new thread
4. Server sends "Hello client, this is the server."
5. Client should receive the message now, but it does not.
6. New thread on server sleeps for 5 seconds
7. Thread exits
8. *Now* the client receives the server's message, even though it was sent 5 seconds ago. Why?

Comment: set `$CLIENT` to autoflush after the accept?

Comment: Is it possible that the server thread is blocking in the $thread->detach method and therefore the write on $CLIENT is not executing until the worker thread exits?

Comment: @feroze - the extra thread keeps the connection open for 5 seconds (though I'm not sure exactly how -- the thread has a private copy of `$CLIENT` and the connection doesn't close until all the copies are out of scope, maybe), but it doesn't delay the write to `$CLIENT`.

Comment: print $CLIENT "$server_message\n" ? #wild guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $server_message = do { local $/; <$SOCK> }
```

in the client script smells funny to me. By setting `$/` to `undef`, you are asking the `<$SOCK>` statement to read all input from the handle `$SOCK` until end of file. In this context, end of file means that the other end of the socket has closed the connection.

The server is delivering the message, as you can see if you change the line above to something like

```
print "Received message: ";
print while $_ = getc($SOCK);
```

(this will also hang for 5 seconds when the input stream is exhausted, but it will at least display each character in the input in the meantime).

It is a "feature" that one end of a TCP socket connection can never really know whether the other end of the connection is still alive. Network programmers resort to other conventions -- encoding the message length at the beginning of each message, ending each message with a special token, implementing heartbeats -- to determine how much input can safely be read from a socket (you might also want to look into the 4-argument version of [`select`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#select))

For this problem, one possibility is to apply the convention that all messages from the server should end in a newline. Change the server script to say

```
print $CLIENT $server_message, "\n";
```

and change the client script to say

```
my $server_message = do { local $/="\n"; <$SOCK> };  # if you're paranoid about $/ setting
my $server_message = <$SOCK>;                        # if you're not
```

and you will get results closer to what you expect.

Comment: I wound up fixing this by sending the encoded length at the beginning of the message.  Works fine now. (I couldn't terminate my messages with newlines, because this needs to handle messages that might have newlines embedded)